# TransactionRequiredException Entitymanager refresh Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I am new to Spring an Springboot. I have got a SpringbootApplication and an Oracle DB with lots of PL/SQL Procedures and these change the state of the DB all the Time. So I tried to check in my Application if there were any changes with PersistenceUnit.isLoaded(entity) and if so I tried to refresh the entity with EntityManager.refresh(entity).

But I got an javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread

First: are my thoughts correct or is there a better solution for keeping the data updated?
Second: Why is the EntityManager not available? Does this mean the EntityManager is running in another Thread? I did not create one.

I hope, anyone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please add code snippet on where you call the entity manager. My guess is that you did not specify a transaction, @Transactional or via session.beginTransaction().

Comment: I was just tried to add some code snippets and rerun the application to add the errormessage. And what happend I got no Error. I dont Know what I have changed. But thanks for the reply.